# Extrapolate Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables in my database.
One holds transaction data and the other holds development periods.

```
Year,   DevelopmentPeriod,   Amount
2018,   9,                   13200
2018,   10,                  13200
2018,   11,                  17625
2018,   12,                  17625
2018,   13,                  13200.0165
2018,   14,                  13200.0165
2018,   15,                  13200.0165

UnderwritingYear,   DevelopmentPeriod
2018,               1
2018,               2
2018,               3
2018,               4
2018,               5
2018,               6
2018,               7
2018,               8
2018,               9
2018,               10
2018,               11
2018,               12
2018,               13
2018,               14
2018,               15
2018,               16
2018,               17
2018,               18
2018,               19
2018,               20
2018,               21
2018,               22
2018,               23
```

How can I extrapolate the data into the future development periods like below?

```
Year,   DevelopmentPeriod,   Amount
2018,   16,                  13200.0165
2018,   17,                  13200.0165
...
2018    22,                  13200.0165
2018    23,                  13200.0165
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: What is the logic here? What have *you* tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `cross apply`:

```
select t2.*, t1.amount
from table2 t2 cross apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table1 t1
      where t1.year = t2.UnderwritingYear and
            t1.DevelopmentPeriod <= t2.DevelopmentPeriod
      order by t1.DevelopmentPeriod desc
     ) t1;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Issue I couldn't get round was returning each of the amounts when doing a cross apply but you've got round it by selecting top and ordering by dev period desc.